# Не работает кириллица на виртуальном хостинге dompdf

Tags: php, dompdf

Всем привет. Сделал через библиотеку dompdf генератор pdf в нужном мне формате. Код тут не столь важен, вот почему: на локальном сервере (win7/openserver) все работает хорошо. Т.е. генерируется нормальный pdf файл. Но при загрузке на хостинг (reg.ru) символы кириллицы меняются на "?".

Каким образом я могу посмотреть отличия сервера reg.ru от настроек openserver'a? Как мне найти проблему?

Попробовал сделать все, что написано в документации и все советы на основном сайте SO. Все, что связано с самим кодом, не помогает никак.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно поможет создание .htaccess и прописать там:

```
RewriteBase /
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

и на самой странице прописать:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: Уже стоит, не помогло. Во всех файлах также прописана кодировка.

Comment: С reg.ru, честно говоря не знаком, поэтому не могу сказать какие у них настройки сервера, но думаю было бы проще написать в тех.поддержку и узнать какие у них установлены параметры сервера.

Comment: Уже написал, жду ответа от них. Но на любом виртуальном сервере такая же проблема